# Convert objective-c call to swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to convert some Objective-C to Swift code.

How can I convert this as I couldn't find any equivalent in swift.

```
((void (*)(id, SEL, id, id))objc_msgSend)(anObject, mySelector, anotherObject, lastObject)
```

Comment: Do you really need to call objc_msgSend directly?

Comment: No I'm just looking for the equivalent of this in swift. If I'm right objc_msgSend doesn't exist in swift as "swift is objective-c without message".

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.1**

```
let handle : UnsafeMutableRawPointer! = dlopen("/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib", RTLD_NOW)
unsafeBitCast(dlsym(handle, "objc_msgSend"), to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector!,Any?,Any?)->Void).self)(anObject,#selector(mySelector),anotherObject,lastObject)
dlclose(handle)
```

You could alternatively use `class_getMethodImplementation`

```
unsafeBitCast(class_getMethodImplementation(type(of: anObject), #selector(mySelector)), to:(@convention(c)(Any?,Selector!,Any?,Any?)->Void).self)(anObject,#selector(mySelector), anotherObject,lastObject)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Objective-C Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html) has all the runtime functions listed.

Some of the functions have a Swift representation, some don't. For example, [class_getName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/class_getName) is available in Swift, but [sel_getName](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/sel_getName) is not.

The function [objc_msgSend](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_msgSend) is not available to Swift.

---

After a quick search, I found this: [Call a method from a String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245262/qa-call-a-method-from-a-string-in-swift). Create an Objective C wrapper for objc_msgSend that will do the work for you. Not a great answer, but it seems to be the working solution for now.