# Send string to object as a method

Tags: ios, swift

In ruby I can pass a string into the `send` method to run that method:

```
coolObject.send("some_method") // Same as coolObject.some_method
```

How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: http://freecake.yayuhh.com/simple-reflection-in-swift/

Comment: And see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060667/does-swift-support-reflection

Comment: This seems like an important treatment of the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245262/qa-call-a-method-from-a-string-in-swift

Comment: Here's a tutorial on the subject: http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/06/05/instantiating-classes-by-name-in-swift/