# How can I invoke a class method in Swift if I only have the string?

Tags: javascript, swift, cordova, healthkit

I am writing a cordova plugin for HealthKit and my task is to make sure that we can dynamically read more or less data from HK. Im doing the native part in swift. But I mostly write JavaScript so I am a bit lost in with the Swift part.

I want to be able to dynamically invoke methods having only a string.

```
let store = HKHealthStore()

    do {
        let bloodType: HKBloodTypeObject = try store.bloodType()
...
```

That is an example to read blood type. I am not a Swift developer, but is there any way I can do this dynamically, like I would do in javascript:

```
... // assuming this function receives a string as paramater
let param[0] = try store[param[0]]() // <-- how to do this in Swift?
```

then i can talk to a server and get a list of characteristics and load them dynamically from healthkit without having to update my code and hardcode for each possible characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mapping from your parameter strings to an API enumeration.

```
enum API: String {
    case function1 = "function1"
    case function2 = "functionTwo"
    case function3 = "threethreethree"
}
```

Create a relay function that maps the API enumeration to the Swift function.

```
func callTheCorrectFunction(_ api: API) {
    switch api {
    case .function1: updateBlood()
    case .function2: spinAround()
    case .function3: jump()
    }
}
```

Construct your function call using enum's `rawValue` initializer.

```
let param = fromSomeJsonStrings[0]
let api = API(rawValue: param)
callTheCorrectFunction(api)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary mapping from `[String: Function]` in much the same way.

```
typealias Function = () -> ()
let dict = {
    "function1": updateBlood,
    "function2": spinAround,
}
dict[param[0]]()
```

Comment: Is there something I do not understand or in the end here you are also hardcoding updateBlood(), spinAround(), etc?

Comment: I mean... you'll have to hardcode the method at some point. That's how you'll know what method to call. This is just introducing a mapping between strings and functions, though.

Comment: i understand but then i am in the same problem.
the thing is that as apple extends HKHealthStore i want to be able to read new properties dynamically without having to modify the plugin... so I need to be able to do HKHealthStore['somethingNew']()

Comment: No, that solves your problem. Imagine you want to read the string "bio" from a JSON file and call the `biologicalSex()` function in the `HKHealthStore`. All you need, at the very lowest level, is a function that takes a string, performs an if statement (ie. if string == "bio"), and then calls `biologicalSex()`. I gave you a bit of a safer version but the idea is the same.

Comment: Hey thanks for going deep with me in this but it does not solve my problem.
I want the json file to send 'biologicalSex' not 'bio', because then i dont want a dictionary that i have to expand everytime healthkit expands... i want to get the string from the json and invoke a method whose name is that string.

Comment: Ah, I understand. You're looking for "reflection" - for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245262/call-a-method-from-a-string-in-swift I'm not sure Swift's exact capabilities but hopefully that sets you in the right direction.