# swift 3.0 let a href from html to call a swift function

Tags: html, swift

I have a html string come from the api service, for example :

```
<html><body><a href="testFunction" target = blank>link test</a>...</body></html>
```

Please note that I put the html string in UILabel and not in uiwebView

And in my ViewController.swift, I have a function :

```
func testFunction() {
  print("I am here")
}
```

What I need is how to call the function testFunction when the user click on the link test?

Thanks,

Comment: So the new user had problem with markdown - have a heart and look to see if the question can be improved before voting it to hell

Comment: what I have is <body><a href="testFunction">test link</a>, and I put this html string in uilabel, what I have to do to when the user press on test link, the function on my swift view controller called?

Comment: thanks @mplungjan, you saved me

Comment: Do you have already the answer?

Comment: @Gregga17 no could you please help me?

Comment: check my answer @HoussamHammoud

Answer (score 0):

At first set this to the label:

```
label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Tapgesture:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: 
#selector(self.testFunction(_:)))
self.label.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Function:

```
func testFunction(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     print("I am here")
}
```

Comment: but what I have to do if for example I have two < a href> and for each one I have to show different data?

Comment: For the same label?

Comment: Yes, what I need is when the user click on a <a href> I have to show a pop up with a detail of the word clicked. so maybe in some cases I have many <a href in the same label>

Comment: I think it is not possible

Comment: so what I have to do in that case, do we have any method I can do it with, for example if I use a webview?

Comment: If you show it in a webview than the html works as normal

Comment: @HoussamHammoud try to set link using attributed string with tags and on touch event check whether touch was within string of tag to handle action. Example : http://samwize.com/2016/03/04/how-to-create-multiple-tappable-links-in-a-uilabel/

Comment: @HoussamHammoud glad to know it helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read this article : http://codelle.com/blog/2016/2/calling-methods-from-strings-in-swift/

With **NSSelectorFromString**, you can call a method with a string.

Another link : [Call a method from a String in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245262/call-a-method-from-a-string-in-swift)