# How to call a method in Swift 5 at runtime given a string representation of the method name?

Tags: swift, swift5

I am trying to have a dynamic swift program that at runtime will do some actions and convert a string into a method call.

## Example:

```
Array = ["TestMethod()", "TestMethod2()"]
```

I want to essentially say

```
if the sky is blue{
  convertStringToMethodCall(Array[0])
}
```

## The goal is for the *TestMethod()* to actually get called at runtime.

## NOTE: This must be one in Swift 5.

Comment: This question has some good details, but it's out of date and the language has changed significantly since then. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245262/call-a-method-from-a-string-in-swift

Comment: I wonder what use case this is for ?

Comment: Read from a file, write some swift code, and have the swift code checking dynamically conditions, and if certain dynamic conditions pass, call a method that is in text form.

Comment: Methods cannot be "in text form" in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response of others and more digging, this cannot currently be done using Swift 5.x or later! If you too are trying t do this, you will need to find another solution.